# How do I check for an ID value in more than one table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
if not exists(SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE1 WHERE ID=@ID)

BEGIN

END
```

I want to check for this ID value in MYTABLE2 as well..how should I write the IF condition ?? i want to check that a certain ID doesnt exist in any of the two tables.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `UNION ALL`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM
                        (SELECT ID FROM MyTable1
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT ID FROM MyTable2) Table
               WHERE ID = @ID)
BEGIN
...
END
```

Comment: @Gage - Sorry! It happens a lot on the easy ones.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
if (not exists(SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE1 WHERE ID=@ID)) 
     AND (not exists(SELECT 1 FROM MYTABLE2 WHERE ID=@ID))

BEGIN

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want -

If you want to check that the ID exists in either ONE of the tables then use UNION ALL. you could use JNK's answer.

If you want to check that the ID exists in both tables then use INNER JOIN.

If not exists
    (select top 1 from table1 a inner join
                Table2 b on a.ID = b.ID where a.ID = @ID)
BEGIN
END

Hope this helps.

Comment: Need to add a where clause to limit the select to only the ID that we are looking for in both tables. `if not exists (select top 1 from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.ID = b.ID where a.ID = @ID) BEGIN END`

Comment: Thanks ... I had noticed that and was editing my post while you noticed. Fixed the missing a.id.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    blah.ID
FROM
    MYTABLE1 as blah
WHERE
    blah.ID IN (some range of ints)
```

If you get no results then you know it does not exist

Comment: He wants to check 2 tables at the same time.

Comment: OP asked about searching for an ID in more than one table, not many ID values in one table.